# How can I find out the width and height of a modal dialog box on my screen using just javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to find out the width and height of a modal dialog box that I am using:

I have the following HTML:

```
<div data-ng-show="modal.visible" id="modal" style="height: 300px; width: 900px;">
   <div class="block-border">
     xxx
   </div>
</div>
```

I have the following script:

```
$scope.openModal = function ($scope) {  
   var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
   var modal_width = modal.offsetWidth
   var modal_height = modal.offsetHeight;
   var modal_width = parseInt(modal.width, 10)
   var modal_height = parseInt(modal.height, 10)
   var window_width = window.innerWidth;
   var window_height = window.innerHeight;
   modal.style.left = window_width / 2 - modal_width / 2;
   modal.style.top = window_height / 2 - modal_height / 2;
   $scope.modal.visible = true;
```

So far none of my two types of check to get the modal height and width seem to be working and I don't know how to get the modal_width and modal_height ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, you changed your question as I was writing it. Essentially, you need to make sure you are setting `'px'` when setting top/left on an element's styles. Additionally, you do not need to parseInt the clientWidth/Height, they are already ints (and also, modal.width/height is not available). Here's a working function, assuming your modal is on the screen already:

```
function () {  
  // First, I'm assuming the modal is currently on the screen
  // and not display:none, or visibility:hidden. Otherwise
  // we cannot calculate the dimensions
  var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
  var modal_width = modal.offsetWidth
  var modal_height = modal.offsetHeight;
  var window_width = window.innerWidth;
  var window_height = window.innerHeight;
  modal.style.left = Math.round(window_width / 2 - modal_width / 2)+'px';
  modal.style.top = Math.round(window_height / 2 - modal_height / 2)+'px';
}
```

Comment: My problem is not yet at the line where I am setting px. The problem is that modal_width and modal_height are not getting set to the correct values. btw thanks for the px suggestion. That will be good for later.

Comment: @SamanthaJ Make sure the modal element is on the screen and not hidden, otherwise the browser cannot calculate the dimensions of the element correctly. If you want it to not be seen yet, you can set it's opacity to 0, or absolutely position it off screen.